# transfer file by UDP but guaranti file not lost

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a project require using UDP protocol to transfer file but still guaranty the feature of TCP protocol. That means we have the speed of UDP and the file not lost.

I've already have:

Server:

```
public class UDPServer {    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here 
        int port = 6788;
        DatagramSocket sk = new DatagramSocket(port);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
        while(true){

            DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            sk.receive(request);

            String msg = (new String(request.getData()));            
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.getBytes().length, request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
            sk.send(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class UDPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
        DatagramSocket sk = new DatagramSocket();


        String msg = "message send";
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        int port  = 6788;
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.getBytes().length, addr, port);
        sk.send(request);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        sk.receive(reply);
        System.out.println("packet da nhan duoi client" + new String(reply.getData()));
        sk.close();
    }
}
```

and can you help me any suggest to guaranty file not lost ?. tks

Comment: Do you mean TCP protocol instead of "TDP"?

Comment: my mistake, I mean TCP-edited

Comment: You cannot do that out of the box. You have to implement your own protocol on top of udp and ack reception yourself. Mind that you will also have to keep track of the order yourself.

Comment: You have an unrealistic goal here.  TCP is more or less already written on top of UDP (which is basically a bare bones IP packet).  First, it would be impossible to guarantee UDP speeds (because you have to resend lost packets--so right away there has to be a drop in UDP speed).  Second, if you were able to increase the speed, then you essentially would be rewriting the TCP protocol to be more efficient.

Comment: The best you can do is to calculate/estimate the packet loss rate and then write your protocol accordingly--but TCP already does this.

Comment: That means make sure the bytes is not missing. And how to do that?
do I sent the length of file and check it on server to avoid missing byte

Comment: @phongly By following the TCP protocol.  At a high level, TCP means that you get an ACK for each packet so the sender knows whether or not to resend a packet.  At a lower (more detailed) level, TCP sends a large number of packets and the receiver ACKs that large number of packets (a window) all at once.  The window keeps increasing while no packets are lost (increases bandwidth) and shortens the window when packets are lost (decreases the bandwidth).  If you look at a TCP transmission, you will see a sawtooth curve where the bandwidth increases, then decreases, then increases, etc.

Comment: @phongly You can try to send the entire file all at once, then send a checksum (or something).  But 1) this will not 100% ensure the file was sent correctly and 2) the larger the file, the more likely that the file will not be sent correctly (via UDP) and simply catching that the file wasn't sent won't increase performance.  If the probability of sending a file without packet loss via UDP is 1%, then you'll have to send it 100 times (on average) before you get the correct file--so you will get a slow down of over 100 times.

Comment: @phongly: No offence, but ignoring that your assumption that you can transfer data faster with UDP than TCP is for most practical purposes factually wrong, having no more knowledge about networking protocols than you obviously have, you will not be able to solve this problem.

Comment: @jarnbjo Since I already (essentially) stated what you did and obviously you are correct, I just want to correct one part of your comment: you do achieve faster data transfer via UDP.  The problem is that the faster transfer comes at a cost, which is unreliable transmission.  So you cannot achieve a faster reliable transmission than what TCP offers (and I don't think that statement is absolutely true--there probably is a better protocol, but finding one would be a ground breaking discovery...and thus highly unlikely).

Comment: @Jared: It would be interesting to understand your definition of "fast". Here, we are talking about a file transfer and the only reasonable usage of "speed", "fast" and "slow" is in context of the time it takes from start of transfer until the file is received completely at the receiving side.

Comment: @jarnbjo That's a valid definition of speed in this context--which you did not use in your initial comment.  You simply said: "transfer data faster".  UDP _does_ transfer data faster.  This is why I made my comment.  You have to distinguish between data transfer rates and the rate at which a complete file is transferred without error (i.e. packet loss).

Comment: @Jared: According to your usage of "fast" (you need less time, but the data is not complete), I could just as well claim that TCP is twice as fast as TCP if the sender on purpose doesn't send half of the data. It's just, that such an argumentation does not make sense at all.

Comment: @jarnbjo Unless you argue that UDP packet loss is a ridiculous amount (which it's not), then UDP transfer rate is much faster than TCP.  If it weren't, then streaming services would use TCP rather than UDP, but they don't--because UDP has a far faster transfer rate of data than TCP.  I don't even get why you are arguing with me when I agreed with you (and upvoted your initial comment)--not to mention that you simply restated what I had already stated.

Comment: Like @Jared says, you are backing the wrong horse and you will lose.  A protocol that cannot guarantee delivery and cannot preserve data order is not appropriate for file transfer.

Comment: @Jared: UDP is used for real time streaming instead of TCP to have control over latency, not because the network link magically gets a much higher bandwidth because you use UDP instead of TCP. For streaming of recorded content, TCP is usually used because the latency is then more or less irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your all replies, hmm...so coud I need to demonstrate to my partner it's impossible? We can make a small app to prove it. And We start with how could I simulations the ACK action? I appreciate with your helps

Comment: Google 'TCP state diagram'.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite big task, if you really want to implement fast and reliable file transfer with UDP.

With very small files (that fits in a single IP packet), it could be easy to avoid some overhead of TCP (like TCP connection opening and closing handshakes).

But If you are going to transfer bigger files, then you must implement many difficult features, like: flow control, selective acknowledges, re-transmissions and so on. 
So I suggest to use TCP, instead of implementing own similar protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You just CAN'T. It's not designed to be reliable.

If you manage to do it... it just means that you've implemented TCP yourself!, it will be much slower though.